# How to make Telescope ignore files inside node_modules?

Tags: wsl-2, neovim, telescope.nvim

I'm new in the **VIM** / **NEOVIM** world so I probably am doing something else wrong, but from the docs it says that Telescope will ignore all the files registered in the `.gitignore` file, which is definitively there but it still searches in `node_modules`

So this is what I do:

1. I `cd` into my project folder
2. Hit `nvim`
3. hit `<leader>ff`
4. Telescope opens and I start typing, but searches are really slow because they are including `node_modules`

These are the plugins that I have for setting up telescope

```
" Telescope
Plug 'nvim:solua/popup.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim'
```

And then my remaps right from the docs:

```
" Find files using Telescope command-line sugar.
nnoremap <leader>ff <cmd>Telescope find_files<cr>
nnoremap <leader>fg <cmd>Telescope live_grep<cr>
nnoremap <leader>fb <cmd>Telescope buffers<cr>
nnoremap <leader>fh <cmd>Telescope help_tags<cr>
```

All this is running in a **WSL** terminal with Ubuntu. What am I missing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just add

```lua
require('telescope').setup{ 
  defaults = { 
    file_ignore_patterns = { 
      "node_modules" 
    }
  }
}
```

to your `init.lua`

Answer (score 3):

Install BurntSushi/ripgrep
See telescope readme under Suggested dependencies
Then put node_modules in your .gitignore and your good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, if the `file finder` does not ignore your `.gitignore` files you need to install `BurntSushi/ripgrep`, if your error continue after that, use `:checkhealth telescope` for more info about plugin errors.

Good luck!! and sorry for my bad english...

Comment: This is the right solution I believe. `file_ignore_patterns` make it very slow.

Answer (score 1):

You need some customization for rg:

```
--ignore-file <PATH>...                  
    Specifies a path to one or more .gitignore format rules files. These patterns
    are applied after the patterns found in .gitignore and .ignore are applied
    and are matched relative to the current working directory. Multiple additional
    ignore files can be specified by using the --ignore-file flag several times.
    When specifying multiple ignore files, earlier files have lower precedence
    than later files.
```

Add to config for nvim:

```
require('telescope').setup{
  defaults = {
    vimgrep_arguments = {
      'rg',
      '--color=never',
      '--no-heading',
      '--with-filename',
      '--line-number',
      '--column',
      '--smart-case',
      '--ignore-file',
      '.gitignore'
    },
```